# Faker.credit_card_number - Is it expected that it's not faster from a performance stand point?

Tags: python, performance, faker

Does it really take 20mins to write 10000 records? Or it's way the code is written which could be optimized?

It takes less than 1 minute or so if random number generators are used.

```
import random
import csv
from faker import Faker

def PanGeneratorType():
    fake = Faker()
    Card_Type = ['amex','mastercard','visa16','visa19','discover']
    Pan_Num = fake.credit_card_number(random.choice(Card_Type))
    return Pan_Num

def RandomGenerator():
    randCardType=random.choice([3,4,5,6])
    if randCardType==3:
        randCardNumber=random.randrange(300000000000000,399999999999999,1)
    elif randCardType==6:
        randCardNumber=random.randrange(6000000000000000,6999999999999999,1)
    elif randCardType==5:
        randCardNumber=random.randrange(5000000000000000,5999999999999999,1)
    elif randCardType==4: 
        randCardNumber=random.randrange(4000000000000000,4999999999999999,1)
    return randCardNumber    


with open("Cards.CSV", "wt", newline='') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(['CARD_NUM'])
    for i in range(1000):
        Card_Num = PanGeneratorType()
            
    writer.writerow([Card_Num])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look closer at what is in PanGeneratorType(). You're calling it 1000 times.
initializing 1000 Faker()'s, each to run fake.credit_card_number() 1 time.

```
def PanGeneratorType():
    fake = Faker()
    Card_Type = ['amex','mastercard','visa16','visa19','discover']
    Pan_Num = fake.credit_card_number(random.choice(Card_Type))
    return Pan_Num

t = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
   Card_Num = PanGeneratorType()
print("Time taken: " + str(time.time()-t))
```

```
Time taken: 85.47297310829163
```

Much faster to create 1 Faker(), and give it 1000 jobs, than to create 1000 Faker() with 1 job each.

```
def PanGeneratorType(n):
    fake = Faker()
    Card_Type = ['amex','mastercard','visa16','visa19','discover']
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        result.append(fake.credit_card_number(random.choice(Card_Type)))
    return result

t = time.time()
Card_Numbers = PanGeneratorType(1000)
print("Time taken: " + str(time.time()-t))

#for cc in Card_Numbers:
    #print(cc)
    #write to file
    #etc etc
```

```
Time taken: 0.11200523376464844
```